Why is my identity on AWS SES seems to still be using the old API instead of V2 for sending emails?
I'm trying to upgrade the email-sending code to use SESv2 instead of v1, but it only works on my local machine; when I push the (supposedly working) changes to production, it doesn't work and I still get the old limit of 10MB for an email. My user has the SESv2 roles and the email account is verified.
import { SESv2Client, SendEmailCommand, type SendEmailCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-sesv2';
import type Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';
import MailComposer from 'nodemailer/lib/mail-composer/index';

const ses = new SESv2Client({
    apiVersion: '2019-09-27',
    region: 'process.env.REGION',
    credentials: {
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY
    },
    maxAttempts: 3
});

const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
    from: `${name} <mail@mail.com>`,
    to: 'mail2@mail2.com',
    subject: `${subject}`,
    text: `${text}`,
    html: `${htmlText}`,
    attachDataUrls: false,
    attachments: []
};

if (file !== undefined) {
    mailOptions.attachments?.push(file as Attachment);    
}

const rawMailData = await new MailComposer(mailOptions).compile().build();

try {
    
    const input: SendEmailCommandInput = {
        Content: {
            Raw: {
                Data: rawMailData
            }
        }
    };

    const command = new SendEmailCommand(input);
    const response = await ses.send(command);

    console.log(response);
    resNumber = (response.MessageId != null) ? 200 : 500;
    return NextResponse.json({ data: response }, { status: resNumber });
} catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
}

I've tried using Lamdba functions (which turned out not to work because of a 6MB limit), various changes in code, mainly trying out things in different threads (for example: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1430), giving roles to the Amplify hosting, etc
